# How to achieve set like behavior in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-concat

Let's say I have `dogs(dogid)` table and `fleas(fleaid)` table and another one `dogs_favorite_fleas(dogid,fleaid)` a dog can have his favorite fleas listed in the `dog_favorite_fleas`. How can I create a query/temp table lists all the unique sets of fleas and counts them? For example let's say `Rex` likes `flea a` and `flea b`, and `Spot` likes 'flea a`and`flea c`, and`Lassie`likes`flea b`and`flea a`. The result of the query should be:

```
fleas          |count
-------------------------
flea a, flea b |2
flea a, flea c |1
```

**Note**: There are ~5000 different fleas and ~4.5 million dogs.

What's the best way of making this query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) with a `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(f.flea SEPARATOR ', ') AS 'fleas', COUNT(df.dogid) 'Count'
FROM dogs_favorite_fleas df 
INNER JOIN fleas f ON df.fleaid = f.id
INNER JOIN dogs d ON df.dogid = d.id
GROUP BY df.dogid
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1f95a/1)

**Update:** If you want to count how many grouped fleas lists there are, enclose the previous query in a subquery and use `GROUP BY` with `COUNT` like so:

```
SELECT fleas, COUNT(fleas) 'COUNT'
FROM
(
   SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(f.flea SEPARATOR ', ') AS 'fleas'
   FROM dogs_favorite_fleas df 
   INNER JOIN fleas f ON df.fleaid = f.id
   INNER JOIN dogs d ON df.dogid = d.id
   GROUP BY df.dogid
   ORDER BY f.flea
) t
GROUP BY fleas
```

### [Updated SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/98e57/4)

Comment: You are counting how many `fleas` are in each list - and I wanted to know how many such lists exists. in this example http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/98e57/1 the correct answer should be `flea a, flea b, flea c | 2` and `flea h, flea g | 1`

Comment: You've nailed it! :) Change the answer and I'll accept it, thanks